# Data Replication - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

Good day

I needed to create a data replication between two databases. I created the Local Publication with one table for testing purposes. I then created the Local Subscription and it worked 100%. I tested it and the data gets updated. I then started to add more tables to the Local Publication that I created. I noticed that the new tables did not pull through to the new database through the Local Subscription I created. Do I need to create a new Subscription for the updates? Do I need to delete the current Subscription or is there another way that I can just update the Current Subscription?

Thanks

Ruan

Got this description from this Article: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2502/limit-snapshot-size-when-adding-new-article-to-sql-server-replication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start snapshot agent, but check that already replicated tables are not marked for reinitialization, because in such case data from old tables will be transfered once more.

Comment: Hi, do you mean it will duplicate it - "Will be transferred once more"

Comment: No old data will be deleted, but when data is transfering from Public database, that tables are locked, so if table  contains large data and database is in useing state that may cause errors. Thats all.

Comment: I understand. I just went to the local publication --> View Snapshot Agent Status ---> RUN, and it did the job. Where would I indicate for already replicated tables not to reinitialize?

Comment: @RuanduPreez If tables are already are marked for reinitialization, I thing there is no way to avoid it. But before it you mask set in 'Article Properties' -> 'Action if name is in use' on  'Keep existing object unchanged'. But I advice you to test is one on Testing server. :)